# How to open external stored modal on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal for signing in user and would like to show it automatically on special pages if the user is not logged in.
The modal is stored in an external file (modal_sign_in.php) so that I can call it from different pages.

Code of the link in menu bar:

```
<a href="" id="modal_sign_in" data-modal-external-file="modal_sign_in.php"
data-target="modal_sign_in" class="promoted">Login Modal</a>
```

How can I display the modal from any page on load checking if the user is logged in?

```
if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {       
    ??????
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Seems you are on the right track, but what is `??????` and why do you `exit()`?

Comment: ?????? is to express that thats the part where I stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply include that external file in there :

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) {   
  if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {           
    include("modal.php");
  }
}
```

If the modal does not trigger automaticly , you ill need to trigger it, with javascript. Create a button, change visibility to hidden, then connect that btn to the modal, and then you trigger the click.

```
if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {       
    include("modal.php");
    echo "<script> $( '#yourbtnid' ).trigger( 'click' ); </script> ";
}
```

Comment: I have included the file and connected the button to the modal.
         '<button style="visible:hidden" id="btn_login"></button>';
            <script>
                $('#btn_login').click(function() {
               $('#modal_sign_in').modal('show');
            });
            </script>`

Somehow the modal gets always display on top of the page and not as modal. Any idea about that?

Comment: @Beji Much likely because youre loading the modal before loading the styles and javascript, make sure you load it inside <body> tag